# How to select overlapping/non-overlapping polygons from a single shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, intersection, overlapping-features

I have a shapefile with a series of polygons, some of which intersect each other and some that don't. I want to select only those that do not overlap with any other polygon.

I've tried the **Select by Location** tool with **Intercept** but this selects all polygons in the shapefile.

As an example, I'd like to select the two polygons to the right, since they intersect, but not the one to the left. Of course, I can't do this by hand since there are too many polygons.

[image: Example: I'd like to select only the polygon to the left]

I'm working on QGIS 2.10.

Comment: Have you tried the **Select by location** tool with the **overlaps** option?

Comment: @Joseph, how do I mark this question as answered? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working! Add what you did in the **Answers** section just below, there's a green faded tick on the left-hand side when you post it (note that answers can only be accepted **after 2 days** of posting) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it! Used the **Select by location...** tool, chose my shapefile in the two categories and checked the **Include input features that overlap/cross the selection features**. Thanks @Joseph!